# facebook user access token

Tags: wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am working on a simple `WPF` project in `Visual Studio` and I wanted to access `Facebook` and I need the User Token.

I went to developer.facebook.com and registered an app, set it to Native/Desktop in advanced settings `then ->> tools ->> Access Token Tool`. Here it says that I need to grant permission to my app to get an access token.

However, when I click `need to grant permissions` link, I get a very brief loading window where I should get an "O.K." button, but it disappears and nothing happens.

Does anyone know why it is disappearing or how to get it to register so I can get my `User Token` for my program?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I click need to grant permissions link, I get a very brief loading window where I should get an "O.K." button, but it disappears and nothing happens.

it's a small glitch; just refresh the page and then try again- this should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wish this worked. No matter how many times I refresh the page or use a different browser, it appears and disappears extremely quickly. Anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: The page it is loading returns a 404. I am experiencing the same issue.